How to query a field that is in a different format?
In Laravel, if I have a phone number in the format of 1234567890 and I have a Customers table/model with a phone column that has the phone in the format of (123) 456-7890, what's the best way to query the Customers table?
$phone = 1234567890
$customer = Customer::where('phone', $phone)->first();

Format the number before you search it. But unless it's a standard format that gets entered, you might be in a world of hurt trying to guess the formats. I've found it easier to create another field, and when a phone number is saved, write a "clean" version of the number to that other field -- Only digits and the letter x for extensions. Then use that field for searching. Or you could format the phone number the way you want as it gets written. Both would be done with mutators

What we usually do in these cases is use an observer or trait that always creates the same format when saving to the database (and apply the same logic in form requests to ensure a valid phone number is entered). We usually have the formatter in a helper class.
Doing this would allow you to use the formatter to format your number and then apply it within the query:
Simple example based on your data:
class Formatter 
{
    public static function formatPhoneNumber(?string $number): ?string
    {
        if (empty($number)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        if (! preg_match('/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/', $number, $matches)) {
            return null;
        }

        return "({$matches[1]}) {$matches[2]}-{$matches[3]}";

        // Or if you're certain the match will always be succesful, you could return a preg_replace instead:
        return preg_replace("/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/", '($1) $2-$3', $number);
    }
}

$number = Formatter::formatPhoneNumber($phone);
$customer = Customer::where('phone', $number)->first();

You could even make this a scope if this happens often.
